# Función que devuelva la penúltima línea de un archivo grande de texto

Tags: perl

```
doc03053220190606125901(1).txt.total.txt
Tamaño total: 512 MB
Total 43046✔
Total 14758

doc05889820190606122032(2).txt.total.txt
Tamaño total: 1.0 GB
Total 156253✔
Total 761273
```

De estos documentos de texto quiero imprimir solo la penúltima línea (la anterior a la última).

Traté de aplicar la función `pop()` sin la función `push()` para ejecutar nuevamente `pop()` y traerme la penúltima línea al momento de imprimir.

Doy un ejemplo:

```perl
my @arreglo = $row;
pop @arreglo "$files\n"
print @arreglo[-1]"\n"; 

foreach $filename (@FILES){

    ## muestra el contenido de la variable
    print $filename, "\n"; 
    ## abre el archivo o manda una excepcion 
    open(my $file, '<', $filename) 
        or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    while (my $row = <$file>) {      
        chomp $row;
        print ("$row\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución más sencilla sería leer todo el archivo, y sacar el valor de la penúltima línea:

```
perl -E '@archivo = <ARGV>; print $archivo[-2]' doc03053220190606125901(1).txt.total.txt
```

El problema... es que los archivos son muy grandes, por lo que el proceso de leerlos puede ser muy costoso y tardar mucho.

En ese caso, una buena opción es la usar el módulo **[Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File)**:

```perl
use Tie::File;

tie my @lineas, 'Tie::File', 'archivo.txt' or die "ERROR: $!\n";

print $lineas[-2], "\n";
```

Otra opción, mucho más rápida, es partir del tamaño medio de una línea dentro del archivo. Multiplicar por 2 esa cantidad. Usar `seek()` para posicionarte al final del archivo, menos la cantidad de bytes. Leer desde esa posición hasta el final del archivo. Comprobar que hemos leído 3 finales de línea, y quedarnos con línea que está en la posición penúltima del archivo.

Comment: muchas gracias Joaquín Ferrero
implemente tu idea pero en un while para que me recorriera todos los ficheros en directorio y asi quedo: 
tie my @lineas, 'Tie::File', $filename or die "ERROR: $!\n";

while (my $row = <$lineas[-2]>){

Comment: No necesitas ningún while para acceder a $lineas[-2], salvo que algún archivo contenga una sola línea.

Comment: si por eso utilice el while por que hay documentos que solo contienen una linea y a esos nomas les aplico el pop para obtener el ultimo y el push para insertarlo dentro de un foreach

Comment: Otra forma sería: if (@lineas == 1) { $row = $lineas[0] } else { $row = $lineas[-2] }